# SP 2010 JavaScript events

Tags: 2010, javascript, events

I want to hook into certain events on a SharePoint 2010 site, specifically the modal dialog open and close events.

Does SharePoint 2010 trigger any events for these kinds of actions? If so, how do I register an event listener?

Working with out of the box installation of SharePoint and only have access to client side code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To intercept all modals if you don't have control on their triggers, you might want to do a "catch all" proxy pattern:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog = function(options) { 
   console.log(0); //do stuff
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old(options);
};
```

You will want to do that after sp.ui.js loads, there are some ways of doing that but if you have jQuery a simply `$(function() { });` will do.

Now to capture the close event it isn't as simple since the same pattern above doesn't seem to work on the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose` but you can simply attach to it with a jQuery selector:

```
$("a[id^=DlgClose]").click(function() { 
  // modal X button clicked. 
});
```

Comment: +1 But I think you missed the bit where you set `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old`

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined(…)`

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is what you are after, but I post anyhow.

If you make a custom call to the modal dialog, you can execute your own code before you show the dialog.

```
//Dialog Opening
function OpenDialog() {
    var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
    options.url = '/Pages/myPage.aspx';
    options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

The callback function can be like this:

```
function CloseCallback(result, target) {
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        // Your OK code
    }
    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
        // Your cancel code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I won't be making custom calls, I need to hook onto every modal open and close whether custom or built in.