# Detect Modal Dialog Close with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog, popup

In my application, I am trying to hide scrollbars in the parent window when a modal dialog is opened...

I've added this to my Master Page:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.frameElement != null)
    {
        window.top.$("body").css("overflow","hidden");
    }
});
```

This does successfully hide the scrollbars when the modal dialog is opened, however I have been unable to set them back to "auto" when the dialog is closed.

Naturally, I tried window.unload, but clicking the "X" or the "Close" button do not fire window.unload... What event can I capture to reset body overflow here? I am looking for a universal way to achieve this, without specifically setting click events for buttons, since there are a number of ways to close a dialog.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It seems sort of odd to me.

Comment: Aesthetics. In my opinion, it looks much cleaner.

Comment: SharePoint has some underlying scripts that control the scroll bars in some pages. I expect that you may spend a lot of time on this for negligible results.

Comment: Was able to achieve what I wanted by overriding the default SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog behavior in my Master page. Was quite simple once I realized that could be done. Answer is below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution

```
$(function(){   
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OverrideModal,"SP.js");
    });

    function OverrideModal(){   
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog;
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog = function(options){
            options.autoSize = true;
            options.dialogReturnValueCallback = function(dialogResult){
                SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult);
                $("body").css("overflow","auto");
            };
            $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old(options);
        };

        $("a[id^=DlgClosed]").click(function(){
            $("body").css("overflow","auto");
        });
    }
```

Credit to this post for the breakthrough:
[SP 2010 JavaScript events](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57872/sp-2010-javascript-events)

Comment: I have tried your solution Dom Roco: $(function(){ ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OverrideModal,"SP.js"); }); function OverrideModal(){ SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog; SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog = function(options){ options.autoSize = true; options.dialogReturnValueCallback = function(dialogResult){ SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult); $("body").css("overflow","auto"); }; $("body").css("overflow","hidden"); SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog_old(options); }; $("a[id^=DlgClosed]").click(function(){ $("body").css("overflow","auto"); }); }

Answer (score 1):

Who's calling the modal form? If you are by using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)`? If so, you just pass a callback function into the parameters. I'm sorry for not being more useful, but look into that `SP.UI.ModalDialog` namespace...there might be something you can add to the modal forms themselves that would kick off once they're closed.

Comment: This needs to work for every modal dialog on the site, so while I have control over some of them that I'm launching myself, there are still those that are popping up from Title links and Ribbon buttons, etc. So I'm really looking for a universal method of accomplishing this through Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tired something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function OpenDialog(strPageURL)
 {
   var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
   dialogOptions.url = strPageURL;// URL of the Page
   dialogOptions.width = 800; // Width of the Dialog
   dialogOptions.height = 1100; // Height of the Dialog
   dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); // Function to capture dialog closed event
   SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
   return false;
 }


// Dialog close event capture function
 function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, result, target)
 {
   if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) // Perform action on Ok.
     {
        //reset your body overflow here
     }

   if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) // Perform action on Cancel.
    {
    noalert( "User clicked Cancel!");
    }


}

</script>
```

Comment: Will this modify all dialogs or just those that are launched by calling "OpenDialog" manually? I'm looking for an approach that is comprehensive in that it affects every modal dialog on the site.